# Returning std::vector back from a dll results in duplicate definitions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, stl

I am building an c++ application in Visual Studio 2022 that is a complex set of self-built DLL's that are used in the EXE and in some tertiary Python libraries. They share quite a bit of code and and everything has historically worked.

The code works in MacOS, but on Windows a call was made to a certain function and I am suddenly getting an error about duplicate definitions of an STL container it returns.

```
Error   LNK2005 "public: __thiscall std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >::~vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >(void)" (??1?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in second_controller.obj    test_application core.lib(core.dll) 1
```

The code in core.lib is for a `DataInfo` object

```
class CORE_API DataInfo
{
public:

    // Other Functions    
    const std::vector<uint8_t> hash() const;

private:    

    std::vector<uint8_t> hash_;
    
};
```

If I call `hash()` from test_application, the linker error appears but if I do not, the linker error is absent. Because the libraries are all built at a single point in time by a single compiler and not shared outside that build, I would very much like to use complex types and classes in the system of DLL's to prevent having to rewrite an entire legacy codebase.

Is it true, though, that returning a `std::vector<uint8_t>` is sure to cause this error because it is templated, or should I infer something else from the error? I can set `Multiply Defined Symbol Only (/FORCE:MULTIPLE)` to force proper function, but this feels very bad.

Comment: It's generally advisable to avoid using standard library container types in your API interfaces. All kinds of horrific things can happen, including but not limited to different memory allocation schemes. Question: why is "hash" needing to be a vector? Hashes are normally a fixed size. The use of a vector here implies dynamic size. Anyway, consider switching to the PIMPL idiom to hide your vector from the API interface. Then you can make `hash` return something more portable such as a `const uint8_t*` value. And I suppose you would expose a method to return its size too.

Comment: Expanding on the above, since you are using Visual Studio I imagine you're targeting Windows. If your API is exposed in a DLL, you are then sharing responsibility for memory management across DLL boundaries. This is a big no-no. Don't do it!

Comment: @paddy it's slightly more nuanced than "a big no-no", there's nothing wrong with doing it as long as all the dlls and application are using the same, shared runtime library. It's only static or mixed runtime libraries that cause problems

Comment: @paddy I understand it is best to avoid returning STL containers. In this case, all the code is all build by a single compile in a single instance and not shared outside of a single build. I am trying to work within the current architecture because it was built over the last decade. The hash size is a vector because the size/method varies between two types of data.

Comment: Kind of hard to determine what could be a *MCVE*, but post the related code: (the function call introduced, its declaration and definition, the place where it was introduced in). *second_controller.cpp*, the file that generates the link error,

Comment: I imagine there's a `__declspec(dllexport)` hidden inside `CORE_API`. I suspect that this, in combination with a method returning `std::vector`, causes every member function of `std::vector<uint8_t>` to be instantiated and exported from the DLL (you can confirm with `dumpbin`); or at least, the destructor. And in the calling code, the compiler also instantiates the vector's destructor.

Comment: `The code works in MacOS`: do you mean the code has not been changed.  But it gives an error on windows? If so, you can report to the [developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It is and it does. I very much wanted to be able put a std::vector in the interface but this doesn't appear possible except in limited circumstances. It looks like if a vector of uint8_t values are placed in the interface for windows, then the DLL. Perhaps if I make these somehow extern but I feel I have left a good path.